# Firebase Phone Authentication operates with Limits to 5 OTP SMS only- Mobile App in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Need Help from Firebase community !!

We have implemented Firebase Authentication using Phone provider in Flutter .

Below Plugin configured in pubsec.yaml

> firebase_core: ^1.3.0
> firebase_auth: ^1.4.1

> `await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(`
>           `phoneNumber: phoneNumberText,`
>       `verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential authCredential) =>`
>           `_verificationComplete(`
>               `context, authCredential, phoneNum,`
>               `updateWrongPhoneUI: updateWrongPhoneUIWidget,`
>               `duplicateUser: duplicateUserhandler),`
>       `verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) =>`
>           `_verificationFailed(exception,`
>               `updateWrongPhoneUI: updateWrongPhoneUI),`  //After 5 attempts - we are getting response as `too-many-requests`
>       `codeSent: (String verificationIdLocal, int resendTokenLocal) => _codeSent(`
>           `verificationIdLocal, resendTokenLocal,`
>           `updateWrongPhoneUI: updateWrongPhoneUI),` 
> ** //in this callback we are re-directing to input  screen get OTP**
>       `codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {`
>         `print('FirebaseAuth ' 'Code auto retrieval Timedout');`
>       `},`
>     `);`

**Problem**: After attempts of Phone authentication on same Phone number for 5 times, the SMS (OTP) stops flowing.

We are running on **SPARK** pricing plan.

Answer (score 2):

according to their support team the limit is 5 sms per 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The messages are throttled if sent to the same phone number multiple times within a period of time.

So you can do either of the following:

- use a different phone number for testing or
- wait for some time to pass before trying again

Here's a quote from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#:%7E:text=To%20prevent%20abuse,request%20again%20later):

> To prevent abuse, Firebase enforces a limit on the number of SMS
> messages that can be sent to a single phone number within a period of
> time. If you exceed this limit, phone number verification requests
> might be throttled. If you encounter this issue during development,
> use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again
> later.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 

But do we have clear figure/timespan mentioned in any official documents with respect to  'Period of Time'. Genuinely, it seems very generic reference point.
However, in our case the user would get difference of 2-3 min user journey during resend of SMS flow. Wouldn't be that fine?

I am bit worried and wondering if we could increase the limit of SMS by any configuration console during a given time period

Answer (score 0):

**Now you can able to add upto 10 fictional(test) phone numbers.**

Means you can able to use these phone numbers for testing purpose

1. without consuming your usage quota.
2. without sending an actual SMS.(its works like a user_name password for testing).

now go [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-platform/customer-identity) And enable Identity Platform and click providers then click the edit button on the phone Auth

Then a screen will show up, In that add your testing phone number(ex +919876543210) and your own OTP (ex 123456 )

**Note: before adding your mobile number for testing make sure to remove your mobile number in the existing authentication tab other wise it won't work**